# SELECT MAX BETWEEN 00:01 and 23:59 on set day - SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following function in my codeigniter app

```
function set_day_peak($days, $offset, $network_id){

    $days = $days + $offset;
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(total_online)AS total FROM network_traffic
    WHERE network_id = '$network_id' AND timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL $days DAY 
    AND timestamp <= NOW() - INTERVAL $offset DAY");
    $data = $query->row();

    return $data->total;

}
```

The above function does return a value but its not accurate, what i need when i call

```
$this->set_day_peak(1,7,14)
```

is for it to return the max(total_online) from 00:01 to 23:59 on day 1 with a 7 day offset or (8 days ago).

As i am not brilliant with sql yet the only solution i could manage would be to use php to set the timestamps ie `($day_start and $day_end)` then use `SELECT MAX BETWEEN` but i would like to see if it can be done with pure SQL Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't events in the first and last minutes of the day of interest?

Comment: What is 'day 1 with a 7 day offset'?  Do you mean day 0 = Sunday, day 1 = Monday, ...; so you want the data for the Monday that is 7 or more days ago?

Comment: The first and last mins do matter, my mistake.Day 1 with a 7 day offset means 8 days ago, day 6 with a 7 day offset means 13 days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function set_day_peak($days, $offset, $network_id){

    $days = $days + $offset;
    $next = $days - 1;
    $query = $this->db->query("
       SELECT MAX(total_online) AS total
         FROM network_traffic
        WHERE network_id = '$network_id'
          AND timestamp >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL $days DAY) 
          AND timestamp <  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL $next DAY)");
    $data = $query->row();

    return $data->total;
}
```

This formatting (whether legal or not) makes the SQL structure clear.  The DATE function truncates the time value part of its argument expression.  The comparison with a timestamp 'adds zeros back' for the time components.  This should select the maximum of all values recorded for a given 24 hour period.  The asymmetric conditions ('>=' vs '<') are important.

An alternative formulation would be:

```
function set_day_peak($days, $offset, $network_id){

    $days = $days + $offset;
    $query = $this->db->query("
       SELECT MAX(total_online) AS total
         FROM network_traffic
        WHERE network_id = '$network_id'
          AND DATE(timestamp) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL $days DAY)");
    $data = $query->row();

    return $data->total;
}
```

This may not be as efficient as it is much harder for the optimizer to use an index on `timestamp` because of the function call on `timestamp`.  You should experiment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you wanto to drop time part, so you can use date function which drops time.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(total_online)AS total FROM network_traffic
WHERE network_id = '$network_id' AND timestamp >= date(NOW() - INTERVAL $days DAY) 
AND timestamp <= date(NOW() - INTERVAL $offset DAY)");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its still not returning the accurate data, i need it to return max(total_online) between 00:01 and 23:59 on the set day.

Comment: Thanks again, but it is still returning inaccurate data, ie im getting the same result from 8 days as i am from 7. I think my code and the code you posted both check between the current time of day instead of 00:01 and 23:59

Comment: Any chance you can give an exact detailed example what date you want to see etc to improve answers?

Comment: my answer gaves you 2012-11-03 00:00 to 2012-11-04 00:00 (with these values set_day_peak(1,7,14)). To take 2012-11-03 00:00 to 2012-11-03 23:59 you just need to drop equal as my previous answer like `timestamp < date(NOW() - INTERVAL $offset DAY)`

Comment: This coincidentally works when `$days` is 1; it produces the wrong results when `$days` is a value larger than 1.  The core idea, though, is right on target.